# Changing the URL string in app.post for express JS

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, routes

this is my first post and I am trying to get back to technology after a break of few years. Really enjoying coding again and decided to learn the MERN stack first. I went through some tutorials and then started to build a website for my business. Created a few pages here and there and was fairly successful to build most things via express, HTML and CSS, until I hit a situation.

Question.- I have an app.post for my '/ranking' route and in this function I am performing some logic. This app.post is being called from the '/ranking' page when the user hits the "View Profile" button. The idea is to pick up unique ID as the value from the HTML template, pass it onto app.post. Then perform the business logic, which includes finding the unique values of the unique ID from the DB. Once this is done, pass it over to a /profile page with res.render. Now this is all working fine. However, after the res.render("profile") call, even though the website is going correctly to the page that I want it to, the url reads
http://localhost:3000/ranking (This is the page from where the post call made). Instead I want it to read,
http://localhost:3000/profile

If there is a solution for this please do let me know. Also if the answer implies that I haven't understood certain key concepts about express and routing, please pass me in that direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: geez I spent 3 hours trying to figure it out...thanks a ton bud

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the route and the filename you pass to `render` are entirely independent.

If you want to redirect someone to a different URL, then you need to respond to the request using `res.redirect` and not `res.render`.